# HIding behind a proxy did not seem to work?

Tags: proxy, browser, ip-address, anonymous

I often visit various sites and like to do so anonymously from behind a proxy. However, it seems as if some websites are still able to detect my real IP address. I know this because they use the IP address to attempt to geolocate me for services.

1. How did they actually get my real IP Address if I am using a proxy?
2. How can I truly hide myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most proxies you'll find online are so-called 'transparant proxies'. This means they identify themselves as proxy and even give your real IP-address to the site.
These proxies are commonly used to load pages on the proxy-server instead of your PC.

IP proxies won't protect you at all, to be honest.

What you need are VPN's (Virtual Private Networks) a.k.a. Network Tunnel.
VPN's allow you to do everything online via an external PC inside that network. You'll get that PC's IP and all loading etc happens on that PC.

Not all VPN's are undetected. If you always want to browse the web anonymously, you'll need to find some HQ VPN's (barely for free) and you'll need to change VPN frequently.

Try searching on HideMyAss, SecurityKISS, ... or maybe even the TOR-network